# Django served ods map tiles induce Edge's Visual Search tool

Tags: html, django, microsoft-edge, opendatasoft

My Django project utilizes the [opendatasoft map widget](https://help.opendatasoft.com/widgets/#/api/ods-widgets.directive:odsMap) and had this "Visual Search" issue when viewing the site on MS Edge. After some investigation, I found out the problem is quite strange...

Viewing the map just through Edge doesn't trigger the visual search on the map tiles. However, when viewing the exact same HTML content but served through Django, it does trigger it (see image)
[image]

Does anyone know a way to deal with this? Using the `pointer-events: none` gimmick prevents you from using the map interactively altogether (on all browsers...). It would be great if I could just deactivate the tool altogether.